# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/exolab/castor/mapping/mapping error

Tags: java, xml, mapping, castor

Exception occurred during event dispatching:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/exolab/castor/mapping/Mapping
    at com.test.client.util.bean.XMLJavaBeanMapping.initialize(XMLJavaBeanMapping.java:60)
    at com.test.client.frames.JIFraSarinSolitaireCreation$6.actionPerformed.666
```

I am getting the above error when i try to acces the package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding castor.jar in classpath

Comment: Rhe jar containing the class org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping is not in CLASSPATH of the JVM. Looks like it is castor API.

Comment: yes had to add castor.xml in classpath.

Comment: Thanks alot for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

The castor is an optional dependency in spring-oxm.jar, to use castor to marshaller or unmarshaller XML in Spring OXM, add this castor dependency into your Maven pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Uses Castor for XML -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Castor need this -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```